# Peculiar errors while converting Range and StrideTo into Sequence

Tags: swift, generics, collections, sequence, where-clause

The following function produces **compiler errors**:

```
func iterateColumnsAlongGravity<S: Sequence>(using block: (_ indexes: S) -> ())
    where S.Element == Int {

        switch gravityDirection {
        case .bot:
            for i in stride(from: 0, to: w * h, by: h) {
                // 'Range<Int>' is not convertible to 'S'
                block(i..<(i + h))
            }
        case .top:
            for i in stride(from: 0, to: w * h, by: h) {
                // 'ReversedCollection<(Range<Int>)>' is not convertible to 'S'
                block((i..<(i + h)).reversed())
            }
        case .left:
            for y in 0..<h {
                let indexes = stride(from: y, to: w * h, by: h).reversed()
                // '([Int]) -> ()' is not convertible to '(S) -> ()'
                block(indexes)
            }
        case .right:
            for y in 0..<h {
                // '(StrideTo<Int>) -> ()' is not convertible to '(S) -> ()'
                let indexes = stride(from: y, to: w * h, by: h)
                block(indexes)
            }
        }
}
```

I don't understand why the *compiler doesn't converts* `Range<Int>` to `S` (and other types as well) while `Range` is obviously conforms to `Sequence` and it's element is `Int`.

It's even more *peculiar*, that if I replace `block` with a class method of similar signature, *there are no any errors*:

```
func printIntSequence<S: Sequence>(_ s: S) where S.Element == Int {
    for i in s {
        print(i)
    }
}

func typeConversionTest() {
    switch gravityDirection {
    case .bot:
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: w * h, by: h) {
            printIntSequence(i..<(i + h))
        }
    case .top:
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: w * h, by: h) {
            printIntSequence((i..<(i + h)).reversed())
        }
    case .left:
        for y in 0..<h {
            let indexes = stride(from: y, to: w * h, by: h).reversed()
            printIntSequence(indexes)
        }
    case .right:
        for y in 0..<h {
            let indexes = stride(from: y, to: w * h, by: h)
            printIntSequence(indexes)
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference between `iterateColumnsAlongGravity(using:)` and `typeConversionTest()` that the first one takes the block as a parameter.

Comment: Cross-posted (and answered) at https://forums.swift.org/t/probably-a-compiler-bug-cant-convert-range-int-to-sequence-where-element-int/18232.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During [the discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/probably-a-compiler-bug-cant-convert-range-int-to-sequence-where-element-int/18232?u=kelin) on Swift forums the following information was revealed:

1. What I trying to implement is called higher rank polymorphism and this big feature isn't added to Swift yet.
2. Probably the easiest solution is to discard generics and use `StrideTo<Int>` here.

   ```
   func iterateColumnsAlongGravity(using block: (_ indexes: StrideTo<Int>) -> ()) {
       switch gravityDirection {
       case .bot:
           for i in stride(from: 0, to: w * h, by: h) {
               block(stride(from: i, to: i + h, by: 1))
           }
       case .top:
           for i in stride(from: 0, to: w * h, by: h) {
           block(stride(from: i + h - h, to: i - h, by: -1))
           }
       case .left:
           for y in 0..<h {
               block(stride(from: (w - 1) * h + y, to: -1, by: -h))
           }
       case .right:
           for y in 0..<h {
               block(stride(from: y, to: w * h, by: h))
           }
       }
   }
   ```